# Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit

I am getting this error on a Windows 7 Professional 32-bit machine, on almost anything I do: updating a repo from subversion, accessing a local IIS site, copying a big folder, running an installer. Sometimes, if I try again, it get solved.

I think there is something wrong with Windows 7. I searched around and found posts suggesting to increase IRPStackSize value in registry I did that without luck. I am using Microsoft Security Essentials 1.0.1961.0 as my antivirus package.

Once this errors starts popping up, I have to restart and then after some random time it starts happening again.

Comment: Is your disk full?

Comment: No, I have more then 15% space in my disk. My Page files are also not on the C: drive and I have disabled hibernation as well.

Comment: do you belong to an active directory domain and are you a member of many groups like 1000+ groups either nested or not?

Comment: No I m not I am part of like 5-10 groups only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this tonight and this blog post fixed my problem after changing these two values and rebooting:

https://web.archive.org/web/20141214075131/http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/09/03/windows-7-nonpaged-pool-srv-error-2017

> Set the following registry key to ’1′:
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache
>
> and set the following registry key to
> ’3′:
>
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size

I also noticed that we both have Security Essentials installed. Not sure if that is a common thread, but it is something that could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical behaviour of a server that starts lots of app compiled with Delphi.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/10560659#10560659).

Answer (score 0):

I too get it with a service I have created.  I really don't know much about it.  I have seen it has something to do with the IRPStackSize ([Read This Article](http://blog.rongabriel.com/2010/03/08/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/))